# Writing file into the data dir of another app (root)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to write a file (FlappyBird2.xml in this example) into the data directory of another app (/data/data/com.dotgears.flappybird/shared_prefs.xml in this example). But the code does literally nothing. I request superuser rights in another activity in the onCreate event. Here's my code:

```
Button btncheat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btncheat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String path = "/data/data/com.dotgears.flappybird/shared_prefs/";
            File file = new File(path);
            file.mkdirs();
            path += "FlappyBird2.xml";
            OutputStream myOutput;
            try {
               myOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path,true));
               myOutput.write(new String("test").getBytes());
               myOutput.flush();
               myOutput.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

/edit: I'm trying it like this now:

```
Button btncheat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btncheat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String path = "/data/data/com.dotgears.flappybird/shared_prefs/";
                String filename = "FlappyBird2.xml";
                String string = "test";
                FileOutputStream outputStream;

                try {
                  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
                  outputStream.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }

                final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                try {
                    runtime.exec("su");
                    runtime.exec("mv " + Environment.getDataDirectory().toString() + filename + " " + path + filename);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But this doesn't do anything either. It creates the file in /data/data/my.app/files successfully, but the mv command does not do anything. I see that it requested SU successfully before trying to move the file, so this can't be the problem. Logcat says nothing in red, I debugged it.

Comment: Root does not apply to apps themselves, only (when it even works at all) to helper programs they start.

Comment: What do you mean by ap? Ah okay, you edited it. But I saw other apps in the store which could write the data directory of other apps with root permissions...

Comment: Your application which you are writing can never act as root.  Only separate helpers it starts can.

Comment: So, do you mean the commandline by "helpers"? So that I create this file in a normal location and move it via commandline?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Superuser and moving files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186624/superuser-and-moving-files) which is your own question on the same topic.  You should not ask the same question twice.