# Superuser and moving files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, root

I'm trying to move a XML file from my apps private directory to another apps private dir. It asks me for superuser properly, I grant him the rights but he doesn't move the file.

```
final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                runtime.exec("su");
                runtime.exec("mv " + Environment.getDataDirectory().toString() + filename + " " + path);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Why? filename is "FlappyBird.xml" by the way, and path is "/data/data/com.dotgears.flappybird/shared_prefs"

Also, I tried it like this:

```
runtime.exec("mv /data/data/de.aciid.nullgc/files/FlappyBird2.xml /data/data/com.dotgears.flappybird/shared_prefs/");
```

Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You're executing two independent commands:

- `su` starting a root shell (which you subsequently ignore)
- `mv` ran as you, which is deemed to fail

What you need is a single command like

```
sudo mv src dst
```

Be careful when working as root.

Comment: I think you mean `sudo mv src dst`, as you have it, `mv src dst` will be treated as arguments to the `su` command.

Comment: runtime.exec("su mv /data/data/de.aciid.nullgc/files/FlappyBird2.xml /data/data/com.dotgears.flappybird/shared_prefs/"); didn't work. I just removed the single su request and put it all in this one line. Doesn't move. /edit: Ah, okay. I requested su in a single cmd now (don't know if I have to do so), and did sudo mv src dest in the next. Sadly, it doesn't move.

Comment: @KrauseDroid: It must be `sudo` rather than `su`, but I guess you know. Make you you don't miss the exception (if any), check the return code (must be 0 for a successful operation), and read the process output (via `getErrorStream`). It actually must work unless given wrong arguments.